# Find timestamp for highest number of concurrent users by date

Tags: mysql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table including these columns:

Sample data:

```
concurrent_users  concurrent_timestamp       concurrent_date
3                 2020-06-24 07:20:00 UTC    2020-06-24
7                 2020-06-24 08:20:00 UTC    2020-06-24
8                 2020-07-05 06:20:00 UTC    2020-07-05
2                 2020-07-05 03:20:00 UTC    2020-07-05
```

**I want to find/list the date and timestamp where the `concurrent_users` is highest for each `date`.**

Expected output:

```
concurrent_users  concurrent_timestamp       concurrent_date
7                 2020-06-24 08:20:00 UTC    2020-06-24
8                 2020-07-05 06:20:00 UTC    2020-07-05
```

I tried following approach/query:

**Error 1**

```
select concurrent_timestamp, max(concurrent_users)
from sample_data
group by concurrent_date;
```

But this gives an error as the `concurrent_timestamp` column is not included in the `group by` clause.

When I put `concurrent_timestamp` in `group by`, I get ...

**Error 2**

```
select concurrent_timestamp, max(concurrent_users)
from sample_data
group by concurrent_timestamp ;
```

It does not give the desired output instead just lists more than a single record for each `date`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Why both tags [tag:mysql] and [tag:postgresql]? Which do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In **PostgreSQL** you can simply use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (concurrent_date) *
FROM   sample_data
ORDER  BY concurrent_date, concurrent_users DESC;
```

We don't need the redundant column `concurrent_date` for this at all. Casting `concurrent_timestamp` on the fly is very cheap - overall cheaper than storing the functionally dependent value redundantly.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (concurrent_timestamp::date) *
FROM   sample_data
ORDER  BY concurrent_timestamp::date, concurrent_users DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6749d67e2b9e1f8cc8cacbb517a4c726)*

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

`DISTINCT ON` is [typically fastest for *few* rows per group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860). Depending on table definition and data distribution, there may be (much) faster solutions. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Answer (score 0):

This is a "groupwise-max" problem.  You can't do it with a simple query, you need a subquery.  There are many examples off the tag I added.  Or you can read my blog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in mysql

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sample_data (
>   `concurrent_users` INTEGER,
>   `concurrent_timestamp` VARCHAR(30),
>   `concurrent_date` DATE
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sample_data
>   (`concurrent_users`, `concurrent_timestamp`, `concurrent_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '2020-06-24 07:20:00 UTC', '2020-06-24'),
>   ('7', '2020-06-24 08:20:00 UTC', '2020-06-24'),
>   ('8', '2020-07-05 06:20:00 UTC', '2020-07-05'),
>   ('2', '2020-07-05 03:20:00 UTC', '2020-07-05');
> ```

> ```
> select concurrent_timestamp, maxid 
> from sample_data s INNER JOIN (select concurrent_date, max(concurrent_users) maxid
> from sample_data
> group by concurrent_date) s1 ON s.concurrent_users = s1.maxid;
> ```
>
> ```
> concurrent_timestamp    | maxid
> :---------------------- | ----:
> 2020-06-24 08:20:00 UTC |     7
> 2020-07-05 06:20:00 UTC |     8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c0d674af2af150f073ab031a6b351ed)*

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in the aggregation of `concurrent_timestamp`

```
select
    DATE(concurrent_timestamp) timestamp_date
   ,max(concurrent_users) max_concurrent_users
from sample_data
group by DATE(concurrent_timestamp);
```